# iOS - crash log - 0x8badf00d - what is causing this issue?

Tags: ios, objective-c, logging, crash

I realize what the error log is telling me.  There is a spot where apple is shutting down my app.  It's taking too long to start up, or become active, or shut down.  I can't seem to figure out where this is happening though.  What do I need to move off this thread and/or out of these methods?

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

  [self preload];

  [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:1.5];

  [window addSubview:[viewController view]];
  [NSNotificationCenter postNavigationNotificationForName:whatever];
  [window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
```

}

```
-(void)preload
{

        [[[UIWebView alloc] init] release];

    if (interface == iPad)
    {
        UIViewController *dummy = [[[UIViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
        [[[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:dummy] release];
    }

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                       selector:@selector(preloadComplete:)
                                           name:UIWindowDidBecomeVisibleNotification
                                         object:nil];
    UITextField *field = [[[UITextField alloc] init] autorelease];
[window addSubview:field];
[field becomeFirstResponder];
[field resignFirstResponder];
[field removeFromSuperview];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self 
                                              name:UIWindowDidBecomeVisibleNotification
                                            object:nil];
```

}

```
- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
{
  NSError *err = nil;
  [[context sharedInstance] cleanup];
    [[[[context sharedInstance] user] managedObjectContext] save:&err];
```

}

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
  NSError *err = nil;
[[[[context sharedInstance] user] managedObjectContext] save:&err];
```

}

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
  context *ctx = [context sharedInstance];
  if (ctx) {
    [ctx makeSureYouCanReachThis];
  }

  if ([[ctx user] userState] != userStateUnknownUser) {
    NSTimeInterval ti = time;
    if (fabs([[ctx dateLaunched] timeIntervalSinceNow]) > ti)
    {
      [ctx setDateLaunched:[NSDate date]];
      [[ctx user] becomeFault];
      [[ctx user] delayedBackgroundAuth];
      [ctx authenticateUser:[[ctx user] defaultUsername]
           withPassword:[[ctx user] defaultPassword]];
    } 
    else
    {

      {
        if (fabs([[ctx lastBecameActive] timeIntervalSinceNow]) >= time) 
        {
          [ctx setLastBecameActive:[NSDate date]];
          [ctx synchServerCompleted];
        }
      }
      else
      {
        [ctx setLastBecameActive:[NSDate date]];
      }
    }
  }
```

}

Comment: what is this ugly [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:1.5]; doing in - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions ?????

Comment: Your application is receiving `SIGKILL` from the Springboard because it is taking to long to respond.

Comment: according to the comments, the sleep timer is to allow the splash screen to stay up for a second and a half.

Comment: @objCdev You cannot control the default splash screen. If you want to prolong the duration then only way to do this is to show your own  splash screen(essentially a `UIViewController` with splash image view and progress indicator).

Comment: @Amar - so the timer is the only thing killing me here?  For simplicity sake, if I just got rid of the timer and let it go as fast as it can, then I should not be getting this crash log anymore?  Thanks

Comment: @objCdev Your `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method should not do any heavy lifting in terms of processing time. It should always return as early as possible for a good user exp. If you ensure this then your app should not crash with `0x8badf00d`.

Comment: 8 bad food. If the application crashes with this address then, it is probably that you are accessing UIKit related functions in some other thread.